# How to see which version of http is the webpage running on?

Tags: http, https

Suppose I have opened one webpage for example www.abcd.com and then from the opened page how to check the version of the HTTP? For example is it 1.0/1.1/2.0. Or since in the year 2015 HTTP 2.0 came out so is it that all pages now have HTTP 2.0 by default.

Comment: You can get this by `network` tab in `Brower's Developer tools`, Just press `F12` from browser, check this `https://www.screencast.com/t/Enx28xJK2ybs`

Comment: It worked rightly.

Comment: Woww, Great !!!

Comment: Do all the pages these days use HTTP version 2.0 (is it mandatory?) or it may happen that some pages may still use older versions of HTTP?

Comment: It is not mandatory that all are using HTTP 2.0,